# Properly masking credit cards

Tags: web-application, pci-dss, credit-card

I'm wondering if the following masking of credit card would be considered PCI compliant.

```
######??????#### 

# Is plaintext 
? is redacted
```

Expiration date is available in plaintext

Is it reasonably feasible to infer the original unmasked # using the combination of the 10 available digits along with the expiration date?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Typically, it's just the **last 4** that are shown to the customer, sometimes the **first 6**.

From the [PCI DSS 3.4 Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf)

> Never store the personal identification number (PIN) or PIN Block. Be
>   sure to mask PAN whenever it is displayed. The first six and last four
>   digits are the maximum number of digits that may be displayed. This
>   requirement does not apply to those authorized with a specific need to
>   see the full PAN, nor does it supersede stricter requirements in place
>   for displays of cardholder data such as on a point-of-sale receipt.

Comment: Perfect, but I will add that, with very few exceptions, there is no reason to store the PAN or any other direct account information. Every gateway will return a transaction ID, and that's all you will ever need. Storing the PAN will require a totally different level of security that most sites (including major ones like amazon) can not pass (nor would they want to). Even if you want to "store for later" many gateways will do this just fine, without the need to store the PAN.

Comment: We use an external payment provider, which returns the masked cardnumber as XXXXXXXXXXXX1234.
We never se the actual card number or dates, only the transaction number.